# Bash Script to Comment/uncomment lines in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a standard text configuration file in Linux (Fedora 20).  Most lines should apply all the time, but a few lines need to be "turned on" (uncommented) and "turned off" depending on the machine the file is on.  So the file looks like this:

```
 ; configuration file
 parameter1 = a
 parameter2 = b
 optparameter1 = z     ; only applies to %%machine-1%%
 ; optparameter1 = x   ; only applies to %%machine-2%%
 parameter3 = c
 ; optparameter2 = x   ; only applies to %%machine-2%%
 optparameter2 = f     ; only applies to %%machine-1%%
```

What I would like to do is run a script that would change the file (or copy the file) altering commenting of the lines based on command line parameters.  e.g.

```
 ./scriptname -u machine-2 -c machine-1 configurationFileName.conf
```

This would cause all lines with %%machine-2%% in the end comment to be uncommented (of course, leaving the end comments in tact), and all lines with %%machine-1%% in the end comment to be commented.

Any suggestions on how to do this?  Thank you.

Comment: You haven't tried anything? What's the problem you hit? Have you tried using `sed`?

Comment: I thought sed might be the answer, but I could not figure out how to make it work.  When I have used sed in the past it has been pretty basic.  Can you suggest the syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following script will allow you to "turn on" and "turn off" specific lines. In your case, it will "turn off" all lines containing *machine-2* and "turn on" lines containing *machine-1*. The script is as follows:

```
comm=$1
uncomm=$2
filename=$3
sed -i -e "/$comm/s/^;*/;/" $filename
sed -i -e "/$uncomm/s/^;//" $filename
```

You run it like this:

```
./scriptname machine-2 machine-1 configurationFileName.conf
```

The first sed command adds a semicolon (;) to the lines containing the variable *$match*, if the line is already commented, it leaves it as is. The second one removes semicolons from the beginning of a line.

Comment: This file uses semicolons `;` as the comment marker, not hashes `#`.

Answer (score 4):

- Enable config for machine1 (and disable config for machine2) :

  ```
  $ sed -i -e 's/^;* *\(.*machine-1.*\)/\1/p' \
           -e 's/^\(.*machine-2.*\)/;\1/p' configurationFileName.conf
  ```
- Enable config for machine2 (and disable config for machine1) :

  ```
  $ sed -i -e 's/^;* *\(.*machine-2.*\)/\1/p' \
           -e 's/^\(.*machine-1.*\)/;\1/p' configurationFileName.conf
  ```

Be careful because the '`-i`' sed option will directly modify the "configurationFileName.conf" file.